# Azure Media Player - cache-control

Tags: azure, cache-control, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I'm using Azure Media Player for video playback and that works great. However, the media player css/js/wof files do not have any cache-control headers set. They come from the amp cdn (amp.azure.net). Am i doing something wrong? I cannot find any information whatsoever regarding Azure Media Player and client side caching. What is the recommended way to set up client side caching when using amp.azure.net ?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching, "HTTP is designed to cache as much as possible, so even if no Cache-Control is given, responses will get stored and reused if certain conditions are met. This is called heuristic caching."  In the response to the azuremediaplayer.min.js, azuremediaplayer.min.css, and the woff2 file, I see no cache control directive as you mentioned.  Therefore, there are no specific restrictions on caching.  In most cases this means that all three files should be cached normally.

Comment: Well PageSpeedInsight complains about these 3 files not having an "efficient caching policy". Looking at other CDN, i see that files hosted there do have these. So basically, i was hoping for a version of the media player files that are delivered with cache control headers.